# How do I add a getElement to an Object?

Tags: jquery, function, constructor

I have a simple function like this:

```
function IonRangeWrapper (min, max) {
  this.type = "double";
  this.min = min;
  this.max = max;
  this.onStart = updateInputs;
  this.onChange = updateInputs;
  this.onFinish = updateInputs;
}
```

And I have many `var` calling this function but these `var` must get an Element from HTML. I am doing this, but it is not working.

```
$rangeAge = new IonRangeWrapper (10, 70);
$rangeAge = $(".rangeAge"); // This line is returning error
```

Is it even possible to get an Element that has the same name  of the `var`? I mean:

`$rangeAge` gets the Element `.rangeAge`

`$rangeSalary` gets the Element `.rangeSalary`

Comment: I’m not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Are you wanting to create an html element or get one currently on the page?

Comment: The name of the var is completely irrelevant to the value of that var

Comment: I wanna get an Element from HTML. The element already exists: it is an input.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are trying to initialize Ion Range Slider plugin, please try below snippet. If facing any error, please specify the error message.

```js
var $rangeAge = $(".rangeAge");

$rangeAge.ionRangeSlider(new IonRangeWrapper(10, 70));
```

Comment: Perfect! This is it. Thanks buddy! Is it possible to include a data like `$(".rangeAge").data("ionRangeSlider")` inside this function?

Comment: Actually, I think I don't need `.data("ionRangeSlider")` anymore. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, the plugin will add `data` for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible by variable name, but it is possible as a object variable's property.

```js
var elements = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateElements();
    // Access by element name
    elements.firstName.val('first name');
    elements.lastName.val('last name');
});
function updateElements() {
    $('[name]').each(function () {
        var key = this.getAttribute('name');
        if (!elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            elements[key] = $(null);
        }
        elements[key] = elements[key].add(this);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    First Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="firstName" />
</div>
<div>
    Middle Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="middleName" />
</div>
<div>
    Last Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But my main question is: how do I get an element of HTML after its `var` has been given the `new` keyword.

Comment: Okay, then need to extend `IonRangeWrapper (min, max)` to `IonRangeWrapper (min, max, element_selector)`, then add below statement in `IonRangeWrapper` `this.element=$(element_selector)`. Then the `new IonRangeWrapper(10, 70, '.rangeAge')` will initialize the element as well.

Comment: I think this is it. But console.log returns me undefined. I edited my question to make it clearer. Feel free to edit your answer.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand that you are trying to initialize `ion.rangeSlider` plugin. Try this snippet `$(".rangeAge").ionRangeSlider(new IonRangeWrapper(10, 70))`. Hope this helps.